# Apache mod-rewrite htaccess - dynamic url with parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get the following dynamic URL:

```
http://example.com/pdfs/viewpdf?id=1494
```

To be rewritten in the browser's address bar:

```
http://example.com/pdfs/1494/1494.pdf
```

Basically, the user is entering in a request to view a PDF that is available on the file/web server and based on the ID number provided, the URL is rewritten to go and retrieve the document from a sub-folder under `DOCUMENT_ROOT/pdfs/` whose folder name matches the ID provided along with the PDF filename matching the same ID. What can I try next? Everything I've tried does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following rule in root/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
#1 Iteration)Redirect "/pdfs/viewpdf/?id=123" to "/pdfs/123/123.pdf"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pdfs/viewpdf/?\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /pdfs/%1/%1.pdf? [L,R]
#2 iteration) internally map "/pdfs/123/123.pdf" to "/pdfs/viewpdf/?id=123"
RewriteRule ^pdfs/[^/]+/([^.]+)\.pdf$ /pdfs/viewpdf/?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me!  Thank you for your help!  You helped restore my sanity! LOL.

Comment: UPDATE: This worked fine for on a dedicated Red Hat server...but for the life of me, when I tried this exact same file on a DreamHost shared server I'm back at square one.  It doesn't work anymore.  I've used the above with htaccess Tester @ http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it fails there too.  It says THE_REQUEST is not supported.  Any other suggestions please?